# Search for a String in a file and save the string after it to a variable

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, variable, string

Example:
Lets say this is in a file:

```
AB: Test CD: Testing EF: Rest
```

I want a script to search for CD and save "Testing" into a variable.
I've tried something with `awk` but somehow I'm not making any progress.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` and perl style regex you can use positive lookbehind:

```
variable_a=`grep -Po '(?<=CD: )[^ ]+' file.txt`
```

In bash this says:

- Create a variable called `variable_a` and give it the value of whatever comes out of  the command in backticks
- `grep` should use perl regex (`-P`) and only return the matching part of the line (`-o`)
- The pattern should match 'CD: ' and then 1 or more characters that are not a space (`[^ ]`)
- Search 'file.txt' for the pattern

Comment: You should mention that's GNU grep only for `-P`.

Comment: Thanks alot. Thats pretty good but theres 1 thing im trying to figure out atm. With that way i can print out Testing but the rest too. I need the script to only print out "Testing"

Comment: You mean only prints it if it says "Testing"? because it only print Testing now not the rest of the line, but if it said "Alligator" after the CD it would print "Alligator"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the sample input/output you posted covers all of your possible use cases then...

With any sed:

```
$ var=$(sed -n 's/.*CD: \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' file)
$ echo "$var"
Testing
```

With any awk:

```
$ var=$(awk 'sub(/.*CD: /,""){sub(/ .*/,""); print}' file)
$ echo "$var"
Testing
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Thats pretty good but theres 1 thing im trying to figure out atm. With that way i can print out Testing but the rest too. I need the script to only print out "Testing"

Comment: As you can see in my answer, the script DOES only print out Testing given the sample input you provided so idk what you comment is about.

Comment: Sorry you are right. I meant this for example: AB: Test, CD: Testing Word Two, EF: Rest, ... and print out "Testing Word Two"